# SpeechSynthesis stop speaking after 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, speech-synthesis

I'm a FrontEnd Developer and I'm having some troubles with the [SpeechSynthesis](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) API in React.

The problem is that I need to reproduce many texts, and these can be very long, so what I've done is to split the text in chunks of ~150 chars. This seemed to solve the problem, but recently I've discovered other limitation of this API, because it reads only for 15 seconds, and then it stops.

Online I've found many solutions, but all of these seems not to work anymore, like a timeout of 14 seconds or less, that calls the method `resume()`. So I'd like to know if someone of you already had this problem or solved it somehow.

Today I've added this possible solution, which actually works, but it makes an evident pause between each element of the array.

```js
let readingText = ["all of my strings", "", ""]; //This contains chunks of the same sentence
const synthesis = speechSynthesis;

readingText.forEach((text, index) => {
    console.log(index, text)
    let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
    this.speechSynthesisConfig(utterance);
    synthesis.speak(utterance);
})
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Thank you.  I've been fighting the same problem.  It took me a long time to figure out the 15 second rule.  I thought I'd made my strings short enough, but that can change when you change the voice!

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same issue while building a voice message for a chatbot.

this solution worked perfectly for me.

note : canceling the speechSynthesis before calling the next chunks to make sure it play smoothly.

```js
function makeCunksOfText (text){
    const maxLength = 190;
  let speechChunks = [];

  // Split the text into chunks of maximum length maxLength without breaking words
  while (text.length > 0) {
    if (text.length <= maxLength) {
      speechChunks.push(text);
      break;
    }

    let chunk = text.substring(0, maxLength + 1);
    
    let lastSpaceIndex = chunk.lastIndexOf(' ');
    if (lastSpaceIndex !== -1) {
      speechChunks.push(text.substring(0, lastSpaceIndex));
      text = text.substring(lastSpaceIndex + 1);

    } else {
      // If there are no spaces in the chunk, split at the maxLength
      speechChunks.push(text.substring(0, maxLength));
      text = text.substring(maxLength);
    }
  }

return speechChunks
}


async function speakText (text){
  const speechChunks = makeCunksOfText(text)
    for (let i = 0; i < speechChunks.length; i++) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
      let speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(speechChunks[i]);
      speech.rate = 0.8;
      speech.voice = window.speechSynthesis
        .getVoices()
        .find(voice => voice.name === "Google US English");
      window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
      speech.onend = () => {
        resolve();
      };
      speech.onerror = (error) => {
        resolve();
      };
    });
  }
  
}


async function run () {

await speakText(document.querySelector('#text').value)
}
```

```html
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="add Text here" value="That's great to know For beginners, I recommend starting with basic grammar and vocabulary exercises, practicing listening and speaking with simple conversations, and gradually increasing the complexity of your activities. There are many online resources and language learning apps available to help you with your journey. Do you have any specific areas you'd like to focus on or any resources you're interested in?"  /> <button onclick="run()"> Play </button>
```